# change position of the configure option to top

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-view

I want to Bring configure drop down tab on the top at the right hand side of the product pictures and Short description at the bottom in product view page

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> app/design/frontend/your-theme/catalog/product/view.phtml

There you can see total html code ! Arrange the html as whatever you want .

Comment: i need it using xml files

Answer (score 0):

Typically, `<select>` options for configurable products are called from:

`<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true); ?>`

As [Asish](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/36694/asish-hira) pointed out, you'll need to edit your theme's front-end (PHTML) template files in order to achieve this.